# write or delete string in textarea using jodit editor

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using `Jodit` as text editor and I would like to delete a text within a textarea using `jquery/javascript`, but it seems I can not do it. I can read the textarea with `$('#xxx').val();` but cannot write using e.g. `$('#xxx').val('yyy');`

I am adding some code hoping it will be more clear:

```
<form>
    <textarea id="test">Hi</textarea>
</form>

<script>
    $('textarea').each(function () {
        var editor = new Jodit(this);
    });

    $('#test').val('Bye');
</script>
```

But the string in the textarea does not change.
Also if try to delete it:

```
<script>
    $('#test').val('');
</script>
```

Nothing happens.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the code which is not working (html, js)? The code you provided works for me

Comment: Please provide complete code of what you've tried.As it is unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Please provide code, such that i can help you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to perform operation on editor object not directly on textarea.following example update text for jodit.

```
var editor = new Jodit('#editor');
editor.value = '<p>start</p>';
```

**You can use this editor.value  property to change text.**

For your scenario below code will work

```
<form>
    <textarea id="test">Hi</textarea>
</form>

<script>
    var editor = = new Jodit('#test');    
    editor.value = 'any value here';
</script>
```

Comment: It seems you're right as I have to work on editor object, but following your example i don't get the string edited, but rather I get a new textarea with the new string...

Comment: Thank you. It works. 
I had to adapt it to my case because having many textareas working separately for each page, I was forced to create a new J-editor for each of them. But it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It may be better to use the Jodit provided function to set the value of the editor instead of doing it directly on the attribute. Using an interface like this will allow for forward compatibility if Jodit ever changes the `editor.value`.

In the same spot you instantiate the editor:

```
var editor = new Jodit(this)
editor.setEditorValue('some value')
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you have should work perfectly:

```js
function change() {
  $("#text").val("Changed words");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>

<textarea id="text">Example words</textarea>

<button onclick="change()">Change text</button>
```

Comment: Works with standard html textarea, not using a texteditor like Jodit

Answer (score 0):

Here's the official documentation example hope it is what you're searching for:

```
$('textarea').each(function () {
    var editor = new Jodit(this);
    console.log(editor.value);
});
```

[The doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jodit)